# Spring rest producing duplicate json

Tags: json, spring, rest, duplicates

I have a trivial Q&A app I'm experimenting with that has three classes Quiz,Question and Answer.  The essential relationships are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Quiz {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private Long id; 

    private String description;

     @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private Long id;

    private String description;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Answer> answers;

@Embeddable
public class Answer {


    private String description;
    private boolean correct;
```

The JPA/database is being loaded correctly with a single quiz containing one question with three answers.  However, the corresponding JSON being returned has much duplicate data.

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "description" : "Intro to Spring 4",
  "questions" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "What is Spring?",
    "answers" : [ {
      "description" : "A season",
      "correct" : false
    }, {
      "description" : "A coily wire",
      "correct" : false
    }, {
      "description" : "A wonderful framework",
      "correct" : true
    } ]
  }, {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "What is Spring?",
    "answers" : [ {
      "description" : "A season",
      "correct" : false
    }, {
      "description" : "A coily wire",
      "correct" : false
    }, {
      "description" : "A wonderful framework",
      "correct" : true
    } ]
  }, {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "What is Spring?",
    "answers" : [ {
      "description" : "A season",
      "correct" : false
    }, {
      "description" : "A coily wire",
      "correct" : false
    }, {
      "description" : "A wonderful framework",
      "correct" : true
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Anyone see anything obvious?  I'm using Jackson mapper.

Comment: I have a feeling your JPA performs a JOIN resulting in 3 rows with the same question as you have 3 answers... Can you share the code you use to output that JSON?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Spring CrudRepository so my only code is this controller method    @RequestMapping("quizzes/{id}")
 public Quiz quiz(@PathVariable Long id){
   return quizRepository.findOne(id);

 }

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Set` for questions and answers instead of `List`. Besides, your entities should override `equals()` and `hashCode()` so that they implement equality by  the `id` attribute.

As for the reason why the list contains duplicates, [an explanation is given here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems?_sscc=t#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword). In short, it states that a SQL outer join is issued to the database, and outer joins do produce duplicate results.

An excerpt:

> First, you need to understand SQL and how OUTER JOINs work in SQL. If you do not fully understand and comprehend outer joins in SQL, do not continue reading this FAQ item but consult a SQL manual or tutorial. Otherwise you will not understand the following explanation and you will complain about this behavior on the Hibernate forum.
>
> (...)
>
> Want to know why the duplicates are there? Look at the SQL resultset, Hibernate does not hide these duplicates on the left side of the outer joined result but returns all the duplicates of the driving table. If you have 5 orders in the database, and each order has 3 line items, the resultset will be 15 rows. The Java result list of these queries will have 15 elements, all of type Order. Only 5 Order instances will be created by Hibernate, but duplicates of the SQL resultset are preserved as duplicate references to these 5 instances. If you do not understand this last sentence, you need to read up on Java and the difference between an instance on the Java heap and a reference to such an instance.

While the link and explanation are for Hibernate, the same behavior can be observed with JPA.

Answer (score 2):

Injecting   @JsonProperty("yourFiledName") at the getter method works for me.

```
@Entity
public class Quiz {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private Long id; 

    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
   @JsonProperty("description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
```

/** DO THE SAME THING FOR QUESTION ENTITY CLASS **/

Note: @JsonPropertiy   from Jackson library. For maven user below is the dependency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It worked for me, but can somebody explain me the logic behind this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It worked for me, but can somebody explain me the logic behind this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those people who are struggled with this issue. Just set 
`@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` to `@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`

This solved my problem!